# Passing Parameter with -J var=value works not with Jmeter remote tests executions

Tags: jmeter

I would like to pass jtl file name over command line arguments. commanline lookslike this:

```
jmeter -J JTL=%JTLFILE% -t Metasuche.jmx
```

In Script I am using `${__P(JTL)}`. If i am starting jmeter like this:

```
jmeter -J JTL=%JTLFILE% -t Metasuche.jmx
```

and

```
jmeter -J JTL=%JTLFILE% -t Metasuche.jmx -n
```

It works as expected and jtl file is created in a file as passed in arguments. But if I am starts Jmeter with:

```
jmeter -J JTL=%JTLFILE% -t Metasuche.jmx and -n -r
```

then my JTL values are landing in a new File ${__P(JTL)} in current directory.

How should I tell jmeter to use command line arguments in local and remote executions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the properties to the remove machines via command-line argument you should be using `-G` instead of `-J`

As per [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

> **-G[prop_name]=[value]**
>
> defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.
>
> **-G[propertyfile]**
>
> defines a file containing JMeter properties to be sent to all remote servers.

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I think my problem was a missing additional property file on slave node I started master with -n -r -Gjtl.properties but jtl.properties is a new generated file containing filenames with a unique timestamp over all slaves and this file exists only on master node